# They are the experts on '"whether" their lives are worth living'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, ellipsis, correlating-conjunctions

I found the following sentence in The New York Times.

> When people are in possession of their mental faculties, they are the experts on ***whether*** their lives are worth living. <sub>[(SOURCE)](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/24/magazine/should-i-help-my-sister-end-her-life.html?_r=0)</sub>

Now see the way this part - ***whether*** their lives are worth living. - is being used. It seems like it's a **fused relative** construction, and **whether** is being used as a relativizer.

But I have never known the word - *whether* - has ever been used as anything other than conjunction. So what is it here? Can anyone please explain the italic part in my quoted sentence?

I have found another sentence -

> They are the experts on whether the output from these dams can easily and inexpensively be replaced, not fishery biologists. <sub>[(SOURCE)](http://voices.nationalgeographic.com/2015/06/15/breach-the-snake-river-dams/)</sub>

But this one is a person's comment on a blog post. But the former one is from a reputed source.

[For my own reference: some asides from StoneyB regarding the gap in the clause. [HERE]](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27064926#27064926)

Comment: *Whether* is indeed employed as a relativizer here, and this use in fused relatives is really its core function. The "conjunctive" use is really just a specialized application of the fused relative construction.

Comment: @StoneyB Hmmm...I have never seen such usage...mostly it's after verb or verb+preposition...and then **whether** clause. But this one is really strange. Is it at all correct?

Comment: Fersher. It's the object of *on* here, and the PP is the complement of *experts*. No different from *They disagree on whether ...*.

Comment: @StoneyB Structurally I agree. But syntactically? **expert on A**. "A" is a definite thing. **whether** adds doubt. Either this or that. I preferred or expected a verb like *deciding* after "expert on"..

Comment: @StoneyB I really agree with your first comment. I wonder why they categorize **whether** as a conjunction.

Comment: *CGEL* only recognizes three "subordinators": *that*, *whether* and *if* when it bears the sense *whether*, which it distinguishes from prepositions as not being the "heads" of the clauses they introduce. With respect to *whether* this seems dubious to me.

Comment: @StoneyB I am now not very sure if that is at all a fused relative construction, though it looks like one. Refer to page no. 1073 of CGEL. According to the diagram, there should have a gap for the relative modifier clause. But in our sentence that is missing.

Comment: If it adds *"deciding"* after *"expert on"* it is much clearer, and throws all confusions at bay :-)

Comment: I still really doubt whether that sentence is correct at all. I think there is some gap of meaning. Anyone please?

Comment: I don't know if using terms like *fused relative construction* has in other contexts helped you to understand how English works (it certainly wouldn't for *me*), but if that approach leads you to suppose there's something "not correct" about either of your two cited examples, I suggest it's a bad way to look at this particular usage. If anything, it's the increasing tendency to use ***if*** as a direct replacement for ***whether*** that could often be described as "incorrect" (but that's not going to stop the "questionable" usages from spreading, I'm sure! :)

Answer (score 1):

***Whether*** is a [correlative conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)), which as that Wikipedia link says, ***work in pairs*** to join words and groups of words of equal weight in a sentence.

The specific pairing here is ***whether*** A **or** B, but in practice it often amounts to ***whether*** A or [**not** A], where that second "contrastive" element can be simply implicit, rather than explicitly specified.

In many contexts *(I don't know **whether** you'll agree with me on this)*, you can treat ***whether*** and ***if*** as synonymous/interchangeable, but in both OP's cited examples ***whether*** is far more idiomatic. I think that's because in both cases the "referent" isn't exactly *"A"* (the only specified answer to a question). It's really ***the question/issue of*** whether A [is true or not]. In *those* contexts, ***whether*** works best.

---

To illustrate that last point, note the results from these Googlke Books searches (where ***rule*** means *give a definitive answer/judgement in respect of a question or legal issue*)...

> *We [cannot rule on **whether**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cannot%20rule%20on%20whether%22) something is true / legal or not* (347 hits)
>    *We [cannot rule on **if**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cannot%20rule%20on%20whether%22#tbm=bks&q=%22cannot%20rule%20on%20if%22) it is true* (0 hits)

...where if we change the verb to ***decide***, you'll see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cannot%20decide%20if%2Ccannot%20decide%20whether&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20decide%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20decide%20whether%3B%2Cc0) that in recent decades the "simpler" conjunction ***if*** has started to gain traction - because *semantically,* the verb ***decide*** tends to focus attention on *one of the possible answers* to a question, rather than *the question itself*.